# How to loop through array keys without doing [0]

Tags: javascript

How would you loop through all `0, 1, 2`properties and retrieve a value

Not just by doing it by `myArray[0].postId`, or `myArray[1].postId`. This is sort of doing it manually.

Is their a way to loop through the `[]` numbers `myArray[0].postId`,  `myArray[1].postId` etc .

For example loop through these items

[image]

This is the example

```
export const GetPosts = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return Axios.get('/api/posts/myPosts')
            .then( (res) => {
                 const data = res.data
                 const likes = res.data // gets  the first item within array, and shows likes.          
                const myLikes = likes.map( (post,i) => {
                    return post.Likes
                 },[])               
                 const myLikes2 = myLikes.map( (like,i) => {
                     return like
                 })
                const myLikes3 = myLikes2.flat();
                const myLikes4 = myLikes3.reduce( (acc,post) => {
                    return acc.concat(post)
                 },[])

                console.log(myLikes4) // trying to get all like postIds not just [0]
                 dispatch({type: GET_POSTS, data, myLikes})
             })

    }
}
```

Comment: why not use a for-loop then?

Comment: a `for` loop? ..

Comment: `for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) { // do your magic }`

Comment: I would use forEach loop `myArray.forEach(el => console.log(el.postId))`

Comment: A `for` loop is one way to iterate over an array, but I'm still not clear on how you want to process the data (I think your example is just making things worse).

Comment: works as well..

Comment: how would you better right it crashmstr

Comment: im looking for something es6 friendly

Comment: `for of` is es6 friendly,   `for (const el of myArray) { console.log(el.postId); }`  And has some advantages to forEach if you end up going `async`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe get the post Ids as an array, like this, to stay in the style of the script:

```
const myPostIds = myArray.map( (myEntry,i) => {
                return myEntry.postId
             },[]);
```

This adds myEntry.postId to the myPostIds array for every entry in myArray.

Comment: What is the second argument to `.map`?

Comment: @d-h-e I mean the empty array literally supplied to `.map`, not to the callback. It's the `this` context to use with the callback but there is no `this`, so I don't know why is it supplied.

Comment: I thought the second argument was the initial value of the accumulator.

Comment: @Adder that's `reduce`

Comment: For reference, the second argument to `map` will be used as `this`. You could use it to do something like easily adding each item together with the item on the opposite side of the array 0 and last, 1 and second to last, etc. : `arr.map(function(item) {return this.pop() + item}, [...arr])` or maybe more mundanely, just have a reusable callback to add a constant to each item: `arr.map(function(item) {return this + item}, 42)`

Answer (score 0):

Alot of good solutions, going to piggy back off of @d-h-e comment example, thank you folks for the help.

```
export const GetPosts = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return Axios.get('/api/posts/myPosts')
            .then( (res) => {
                 const data = res.data
                 const likes = res.data // gets  the first item within array, and shows likes.          
                const myLikes = likes.map( (post,i) => {
                    return post.Likes
                 },[])               
                 const myLikes2 = myLikes.map( (like,i) => {
                     return like
                 })
                const myLikes3 = myLikes2.flat();
                const myLikes4 = myLikes3.reduce( (acc,post) => {
                    return acc.concat(post)
                 },[])
                myLikes4.forEach(el => console.log(el.postId));

                 dispatch({type: GET_POSTS, data, myLikes})
             })

    }
}
```